# Delete text after comma Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to search/replace on the following

```
test:stack:over:flow
```

and I want the result to be like

```
test:over:flow
```

so remove "stack" in notepad++

Example on one line `123:456:678` and another with `321:614:241` and I want to delete the `:456` and `:614`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove every "stack" from the document?

Then you could use the replace window [Ctrl + H] to replace "stack:" with "" and press Replace/Replace All.

Update:
You can use the find and replace popup described above with a regular expression to accomplish that. Have a look [here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) on how to use them.

Comment: No that was an example I want to remove From the first : to the second : and keep the second :

Answer (score 0):

Press 'Ctrl' + 'F', that will open the "Find"-window, go to the tab "Replace", and type at the bar: "Search for:" your characters you want to delete, and don't fill anything in at the "Replace with:"-bar.

Comment: Sorry but it's for example on one line
123:456:678 and another with 321:614:241  and i want to delete the :456 and :614

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to find what you defined, but there are many ways to get the result you defined in your question, but that depends on your exact requirements. Here is one that works for your examples with Search mode "Regular expression"

Search for

```
^([^:]+):[^:]+(:.+)$
```

and replace with

```
$1$2
```

`^` matches the start of the row, it is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

`([^:]+)` matches at least one digit that is not a ":", this is stored in `$1` because of the first set of brackets in this expression. `[]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

`:` matches a ":"

`[^:]+` matches at least one digit that is not a ":"

`(:.+)` matches a ":" and [one or more other characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (except newlines)

`$` matches the end of the row, als an anchor

Be a bit careful with `[^:]`, this matches also newlines, maybe it is better to change it to `.+?` (matches at least one character but newlines, and this is done lazy because of the following `?`) or add the newline characters to the negated character class `[^:\r\n]`